# CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter not showing the full array

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I used the code in the following link for my app:

http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/watsapp-custom-listview-imageview-textview-baseadapter.html

But when I'm using CustomAdapter, and set the ListView to this adapter,
The ListView does not show all the objects in the Member_name array.

What it does, is showing only the first 9 objects in that array, then it showing those 9 objects again from the beginning and over and over again, as much times as the array size.

Can you help me?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

You asked for my specific code, so:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(rowItems.get(position));
    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView member_name;
        TextView status;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

            RowItem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
            holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
            holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't send us to some other site. post your adapter class code along with the question for us to help you.

Comment: and how many items are you passing in the rowItems list?

Comment: it changes (using variable), but I tested it with 15 or 46.

Comment: @Setu it changes (using variable), but I tested it with 15 or 46.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the data only when the convertView is null. When a view is recycled you set nothing, showing the current repeated data, try with this:

```
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.member_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.profile_pic.setImageBitmap(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
    holder.member_name.setText(row_pos.getMember_name());
    holder.status.setText(rowItems.get(position).getStatus());
```

Comment: I deleted the if and else statements and pasted the whole code outside and it worked! thanks!!!!